# dpkg: error processing package teamviewer (--install):

Tags: code

[image]

i was trying all solution in youtube, but no one solve my problem.. It's my first time using ementary os, so can someone help me please

Comment: Did you download the proper version? Try https://download.teamviewer.com/download/linux/teamviewer_amd64.deb . I used Eddy from the AppCenter to install it and it went fine.

Comment: Please include what command you ran in your question

Answer (score 0):

1. [Download](https://download.teamviewer.com/download/linux/teamviewer_amd64.deb)
2. Open the AppCenter and install **Eddy**
3. Open the download with Eddy
4. Hit install